# Add external javascripts

Tags: 7, javascript

Is it possible to add external javascripts directly into the .info file of a theme?
e.g scripts[] = http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/jquery.tools.min.js

Comment: Are you just seeking to add the CDN version of jQuery Tools to your theme, or are you *explicitly* asking whether can be done from a theme's .info file?

Comment: It is explicitly to add external javascript to the .info file

Comment: So you wanted to add it to the .info file and you accepted an answer that doesn't talk about the .info file at all and shows the drupal_add_js method?

Comment: Yes if it doesn't work in the info file I'm glad with the best possible solution.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your theme's template.php file use [drupal_add_js()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) to the page preprocess method (or an equivalent preprocess).

```
function hook_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  drupal_add_js('http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/jquery.tools.min.js', 'external');
}
```

Comment: I get a javascript error when using this function, when i put the script inside (footer) html.tpl.php it is working.

Comment: What error? Does Drupal output the correct looking script markup when using this function if you check the source code?

Comment: Adding the options array fixed it. Guess it was a problem with weight. drupal_add_js('http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/jquery.tools.min.js', array('type' => 'external', 'scope' => 'header', 'weight' => 10)); Thnx!

Comment: @Jurgen `drupal_add_js()` accepts also a string as second parameter; in that case, it is considered as the "type" index used from the `$options` array. If you need to set other options, then you have to use an array.

Comment: @drmonkeyninja How to add JS in any module..??

Comment: How do you make sure the position of this script among others? because this should be add after jquery library. And also is there a way to add row weight for a script so that i can place it in a proper place among others.

Comment: It is not working for me. I am adding the code in my template.php file. still no luck

Answer (score 2):

The method of adding javascript depends on for what you are adding javascript for.
There are different ways to add js.

- By defining in the theme.info file.
- Adding it inline.
- Adding an external js file.

You can add a js info file with this simple line of code

```
scripts[] = js/myscript.js
```

Or you can use the php function provided by `drupal drupal_add_js`

This functions lets you easily add a JavaScript file or helps in setting an inline code to any page in your theme and it takes 5 parameters ([you see  it in the api reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/)).

There is an detail post on [this here.](http://safwan.in/drupal/how-to-drupal-add-js-tutorial)

Comment: you cannot define an external JS in a info file, apparantly http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/196874/12010