# Can I add external js and css via module info files?

Tags: 7, javascript, theming, .info

I have read that I can add js and css file via .info files. Can I add external css and js files there as well? Eg http://somewhere.com/in_a_galaxy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

External JS/CSS files can't be specified in the info file at all. You need to add them via hooks, typically I use `THEMENAME_preprocess_page()` for things that need to be included on all pages, or you can use `drupal_add_js()` in your `.module` file.

And you can refer to [this page](https://ffwagency.com/blog/7-ways-to-add-custom-js-and-css-to-a-page-drupal). Here you can see how many ways you can add script/css files.

Comment: Actually it is possible in .info files ... of themes and of modules ! https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/writing-module-info-files-drupal-7x#stylesheets

Comment: @rémy No, it is not possible for **external** js/css files. Take a look: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/working-with-css/adding-style-sheets-from-info-files (very end "Adding external stylesheets"). The right way is to use the `drupal_add_css()` and `drupal_add_js()` functions.

Comment: ups - i guess i was in D8 mode ...

Comment: @MichaLeuth: it is possible also in Drupal 7 to import an external CSS (I did it several times) stylesheets[all][] = file.css into the info file.
Spceified here in D7
https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/writing-module-info-files-drupal-7x#stylesheets

Answer (score 2):

To add external javascript.

```
drupal_add_js('http://example.com/example.js', 'external');
```

To add external css.

```
drupal_add_css('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:regular', 'external');
```